# Race car game using c graphics

Tags: c, bgi

I am trying to create a race car game using C `graphic.h` functions. I plan to make a car, moved by the player, dodge enemy cars. However I am having trouble making those enemies. To create enemy cars, I added a code for a moving car that would go from the top of the screen towards the bottom, but when I run the code, only the car that the player will use is seen (the blue car).

```
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{

    int enemyNormal=0,enemyFast=0,enemySlow=0;
     int j=0;
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\tc\\bgi");
    //variables for active page
    int page=0;
    //variable used to make the road look like it is moving
    int t_y=-300;
    //variables to change the cars position.
    int C_x=0,M_Speed=5;
    int C_y=0;

    while(1)
    {
    //function ensures screen does not flash and animation is smooth
    setactivepage(page);
    setvisualpage(1-page);
    cleardevice();


     //for background i.e side of the road
    setcolor(GREEN);
    rectangle(0,0,1000,1000);
    setfillstyle(1,GREEN);
    floodfill(1,1,GREEN);
    //creating track
    setcolor(WHITE);
    rectangle(100,-1,500,500);
    setfillstyle(1,8);
    floodfill(201,0,WHITE);
    //line in roads
    //makes several rectangles at once
    for(int i=0;i<2000;i+=65)
    {
        rectangle(185,10+i+t_y,205,50+i+t_y);
        rectangle(290,10+i+t_y,310,50+i+t_y);
        rectangle(395,10+i+t_y,415,50+i+t_y);
        setfillstyle(1,WHITE);
        floodfill(186,11+i+t_y,WHITE);
        floodfill(291,11+i+t_y,WHITE);
        floodfill(396,11+i+t_y,WHITE);
    }
    t_y+=15;
    if(t_y>500)
    {
        t_y=-500;
    }
    //for  displaying points
    settextstyle(10,0,2);

    outtextxy(10,40,"POINTS:");

    setfillstyle(1,WHITE);


    outtextxy(100,40,"0");

  //code for making enemy cars
      int i;
     for(i=0;i<500;i=i+10)
    {setcolor(BLACK);
    setfillstyle(1,LIGHTBLUE);
    rectangle(300,900+i,340,960+i);
    floodfill(301,901+i,BLACK);

    //Front
    setfillstyle(1,BLUE);
    rectangle(305,885+i,335,900+i);
    floodfill(306,886+i,BLACK);

    setfillstyle(1,BLACK);
    rectangle(305,905+i,335,955+i);
    floodfill(306,906+i,BLACK);
    }


     //car
    setcolor(BLACK);
    setfillstyle(1,LIGHTBLUE);
    rectangle(300+C_x,400+C_y,340+C_x,460+C_y);
    floodfill(301+C_x,401+C_y,BLACK);

    //Front
    setfillstyle(1,BLUE);
    rectangle(305+C_x,385+C_y,335+C_x,400+C_y);
    floodfill(306+C_x,386+C_y,BLACK);

    setfillstyle(1,BLACK);
    rectangle(305+C_x,405+C_y,335+C_x,455+C_y);
    floodfill(306+C_x,406+C_y,BLACK);

    //wheels
    setfillstyle(1,BLACK);
    pieslice(305+C_x,392+C_y,90,270,6);
    pieslice(337+C_x,392+C_y,270,90,5);



    //Functions that are used to help the car move
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        C_x-=M_Speed;
    else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        C_x+=M_Speed;
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        C_y-=M_Speed;
        else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
        C_y+=M_Speed;
    page=1-page;
    delay(20);
   }getch();
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your display is 1000 pixels tall? Looks more like 400 given where the player vehicle is drawn...try changing the enemy vehicles position closer to 0?

Comment: I cant do that i need the enemy to come from the top of the screen